# How to create an interface between an adapter and a viewholder

Tags: android, interface, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I want to create an interface between an adapter and a view holder (this view holder is an inner class of another adapter) so that I can update the text view (number). How can I do this?

**In detail:**

I have two recycle views (Main List Recycler View and Sub List Recycler View horizontally placed as shown in the fig) one having a number (as one of its item) and other having checkbox (as its item).

[image]

I have two adapters `FilterMainListAdapter` and `FilterSubListAdapter` with view holders `FilterMainListViewHolder` and `FilterSubListViewHolder` populating the fields.

When checkboxes are selected in the Sub List Recycler View, I want the corresponding number in the Main List Recycler View to  update.

For this, I'm using and Interface.

```
public interface ChangeFilterMainNumber {
void OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(int totalCheckedNumber);
}
```

I've checkbox's onClick method inside the `FilterSubListViewHolder` and I'm trying to send the total check boxes checked number as follows.

```
changeFilterMainNumber.OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(totalCheckedNumber);
```

After that, I'm implementing `ChangeFilterMainNumber` interface inside the `FilterMainListViewHolder`

```
public class FilterMainListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
ChangeFilterMainNumber {...}
```

But How can I define this interface inside the `FilterSubListAdapter`?

```
changeFilterMainNumber = ???;
```

[If it is an activity one can define the interface like this `changeFilterMainNumber = (ChangeFilterMainNumber) context` inside the default constructor of `FilterSubListAdapter`. But what about a view holder that is an inner class of another adapter?]

or is there a better approach in finding a solution to my problem other than this?

**Update:** You can take a look at the code here https://github.com/gSrikar/FilterScreen

Answer (score 0):

If I implement the function as you want, I will implement like this:
(This is like an Observer pattern)

```
class Fragment/Activity implement OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener{
    FilterMainListAdapter mainAdapter;
    FilterSubListAdapter subAdapter;

    void oncreate() {
         mainAdapter = new FilterMainListAdapter(this);

    }

    @Override
    void OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(int totalCheckedNumber) {
          .....
         // Update data to sub list
    }
}

class FilterMainListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    public interface ChangeFilterMainNumber {
          void OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(int totalCheckedNumber);
     }
    ChangeFilterMainNumber listener;
    FilterMainListAdapter(ChangeFilterMainNumber listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                            listener.OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(position)
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}

class FilterSubListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


}
```

Comment: How can I get reference to the individual item in the Main List Recycler View before updating them in the `OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener`?

Comment: I saw your project above, I usually do like that: in file `filter_main_list_items.xml`, you put id in outside view like `linearCover`. And in `FilterMainListAdapter`, method onBindViewHolder, you do as above my code 
`holder.linearCover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                            listener.OnChangeFilterMainNumberListener(position)
                    }
                }
            });`