# Is there a way for 2 different RecyclerViews to communicate with each other?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an activity that has two different recyclerviews that use two different adapters. Is there a way for the recyclerviews to communicate with each other?

For example:

userChoiceRecyclerView(second recyclerview) has a bunch of cardview objects that display text

displayRecyclerView(first recyclerview) has no information until you click a cardview object in userChoiceRecyclerView, and when you click an object in displayRecyclerView it will remove the cardview object in this recycler.

```
public class AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnswerViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private char[] mCharacterNameToChar;

    public AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String name) {
        mContext = context;
        mCharacterNameToChar = name.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    }

    public void answerUpdateName(String name) {
        mCharacterNameToChar = name.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public AnswerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AnswerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(...);
        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  // removes the cardviews that was updated from the 
                  // userChoiceRecyclerView
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCharacterNameToChar.length;
    }
}
```

The userChoiceRecyclerView is basically the same as this recyclerview except that it already has information in cardviews. I was wondering how I can make the recyclers communicate with each other

Comment: Callback interfaces can do wonders for communication. Please show some code that you are working with

Comment: Just added a snippet of one of my adapters. What can a Callback interface do? Sorry I'm fairly new to android and java only been coding since late June. Thanks!

Comment: What if you "pulled out" `new View.OnClickListener()` into its own `listener` variable? Then, give that `listener` variable as a parameter to be added to the adapter along with the context and the string? You could then define some "callback" action from outside the adapter class that can reference another view from the Context that you are in

Comment: You can even try using Local Broadcast reciver

Comment: I think this link can help you, I answered the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408588/how-to-create-an-interface-between-an-adapter-and-a-viewholder

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you will need to add a **Clicklistener** for every object inside for ReRecyclerView .

you will need to add this code in your adapters :

```
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
.
.
public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListenerHolder) {
    myClickListener = myClickListenerHolder;
}
.
.
public interface MyClickListener {
     void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
```

and in your **cardView** ClickListener add :

```
holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              // removes the cardviews that was updated from the 
              myClickListener.onItemClick(position,view);
        }
    });
```

now at **MainActivity.java** you can control your objects clicks by adding them in **onResume** at your main .

example:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter SecondAdapter, displayRecyclerAdapter;
RecyclerView displayRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
.
.
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter) SecondAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new  AnswerRecyclerViewAdapter
            .MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            //from here you can send data to your other RecyclerView like this 
            displayRecyclerAdapter = new displayRecyclerAdapterClass(Context,SomeString);
            displayRecyclerView.setAdapter(displayRecyclerAdapter);
        }
    });
}
```

i hope this could help you ^_^